# Identifying coordinate bonds

Tags: bond, lewis-structure, formal-charge

How can we know whether a compound has a coordinate bond or not? I know that I have to draw the Lewis Structure for the compound. But what to do after that? Is there anything to do with formal charges?

Comment: Tere really isn't a perfect way to do this other than by observing the structure of the compound.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing needed for a dative bond is a lone electron pair in one atom and an empty orbital in another atom.
This condition is necessary but enough.

There is also a formula that fails in many cases but may sometimes become handy:
Formal Charge = (Oxidiation State of the centeral atom - 8 + Digit of its group number)/2

e.g.: For SO3 it would be: (6-2)/2 Which means that it has 2 co-ordinate bonds.
However for a compound like NH4+ it won't work.

Of course, safest way is to find out how the compound had formed in the first place.
e.g.: If we know that BF3 + F- made BF4-, we would find out that F- had shared with B two of its electrons, filling the empty orbital belonging to B.

Answer (score -1):

After drawing the structure, you can basically check if the shared pair of electrons are coming from the same molecule. If the answer is yes, then the compound contains coordinate covalent bond.

Comment: You should seriously improve it

Comment: You should also tell the way to identify that shared pair of electrons are coming from same molecule.

Answer (score -1):

Check the formal charge.If the central atoms contains +1 formal chatge then it is donating electron pair to anothe atom.And if it contains -1 formal charge then it is accepting electron pair from other atom

Comment: Hmm, it's not useful to oversimplify it like this. What if the atom had been assigned a formal charge more than -1, like many of the sulfur compounds?